# jquery ajax works only once

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm creatin a quiz bundle and i'm using ajax to load a new question form when submitting one . the problem is that the ajax is working only once 
when i click next i have a new form but then i keep having the old form .

Any Help ?

this is my view code :

```
<form method="post" class="ajax"> 
    <div id="form_body">

        {% include 'MoocBundle:Quiz:form.html.twig' with {'form': form} %}
    </div>   

</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/mooc/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( ".next" ).on("click", function(e) {

         e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: "{{ path('quiz_show_next',{'id' : 1}) }}",
                cache: false,

                success: function (data) {
                     $('#form_body').html(data);
                  }
            });
            return false;
        }
        ); 
    });


</script>
```

my controller action ( i'm creating a new form each time )

```
public function nextAction(Request $request , $id )
{
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $quiz = $em->getRepository('MoocBundle:Quizz')->findOneById($id);
        $this->i++;

        $question = $quiz->getQuestions()->get($this->i);


        $form = $this->createCreateForm($question);
        return $this->render('MoocBundle:Quiz:takeQuiz.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));

}
```

Comment: Your setup is not quite clear. Is `.next` a descendant of `#form_body`? And, if you're submitting the same data to the ajax call wouldn't return the same content (form) each time?

Comment: yes ,next is the submit button of the form

Comment: Thank you @R14, that's good to know but would you please answer the question.

Comment: no , i'm creating another form in the controller

Comment: Is it yes or no? Please take a look at the answer below.

Comment: i'll post my controller action

Answer (score 0):

If `.next` is inside of `#form_body` then use `event delegation`. Change:

```
$( ".next" ).on("click", function(e) {
```

To:

```
$('#form_body').on('click', '.next', function(e) {
```

Each time you load ajax content you're replacing `.next`. Since the `.next` loaded by ajax was not present at DOM ready, the same code that fired for the original `.next` would not fire, unless you use **event delegation**.

Answer (score 0):

#### For dynamics elements always bind event listeners on parents

Here's an example for 'click' event listener on "#form_body" element for every '.next' element which is his descendant.

```
$("#form_body").on("click", ".next", function(e) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i replace but it didn't work ,it's not that the problem in fact if i replace  $('#form_body').html(data); by  $('#form_body').append(data); i have another form but the same one as the old

Comment: Because you always send {'id' : 1} ?

Comment: i'm changing another parameter inside the controller action (i) take a look at the controller i just post it , thanks

Comment: when i click on next on the first time i have a new form than i keep having the same one

Comment: no i request the same url but i'm changing parameters inside the controller  each time i click okey i'm calling the nextAction with id 1 (quiz 1) and creating a new form w question id i ( i increment each time i )

Comment: You cannot successfully persist a state ($this->$i++) in a controller between client requests. For every request the whole stack is rebuild and controller is created as new object.